# Method overloading by return type issue

Tags: swift, generics, overloading

I have unexpected behaviour while overloading methods using generics:

```
func wrapper<T>() -> T? {
    print(T.self)
    let result: T? = internalFunc()
    return result
}
    
func internalFunc<T>() -> T? {
    print("generic")
    return nil
}

func internalFunc() -> Int? {
    print("non generic")
    return nil
}
    
let s: Int = internalFunc() ?? 0
let s2: Int = wrapper() ?? 0
```

Console output:

> non generic
>
> Int
>
> generic

I can't understand why last method called is generic. Shouldn't overload be choosen dynamically? If so, we can see that `T.self == Int.self`, and non generic method should be called. Where I'm wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Swift, ["Overloaded functions are chosen at compile time"](https://airspeedvelocity.net/2014/09/24/which-function-does-swift-call-part-2-single-arguments/).

That means your call to `internalFunc()` inside of `wrapper` will always dispatch to the generic version, because the compiler can't specialize it.

The whole article series on airspeedvelocity is worth reading--it helped clarify my understanding of overloading quite a bit. For example, the next section of the article talks about getting runtime polymorphism using methods on classes rather than unbound functions.